# TypeError: Need a valid target to patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Business_Logic
   excel_format_error_checks.py
tests
   test_excel_format_error_checks.py
```

In my test_excel_format_error_checks.py, I am getting an error `TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: <module 'openpyxl' from 'C:\\Users\\brady\\Desktop\\excel_formatting\\excel_format_website\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\openpyxl\\__init__.py'>`

excel_format_error_checks.py

```
import openpyxl
...
```

test_excel_format_error_checks.py

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from Business_Logic import excel_format_error_checks

class TestExcelFormatErrorChecks(TestCase):

    @patch(excel_format_error_checks.openpyxl):
       ...
```

I have looked at the docs where it talks about where to patch, and it says to patch where the module is looked up. In my understanding, I am looking up openpyxl in excel_format_error_checks.py and so that's where it should be patched.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's happening because you can't create folders in C drive using python. And you have written a file name at the last. Try removing that and selecting a  different directory

Comment: You cannot patch a whole module, you should patch module attributes (like classes and functions) instead. Also, in the case where you import a module directly, you can directly patch attributes in that module (e.g. `@patch("openpyxl.some_function")`). And I just noticed that you pass the module intead of a name - `patch` expects a string.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes that was it, forgot to make it a string thanks!